# Detecting USB Insertion/Removal

Tags: usb-drive, usb, python, script

Is there any way to detect when a usb flash drive/stick/etc gets plugged in a usb port? To be more specific, I need to have a way to detect usb insertion/removal and use this information in a python script. I'm posting here because I am working in the elementary OS. If I'm posting in the wrong stackexchange forum feel free to move it accordingly. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Linux kernels, you can use `udev` to detect removable disks. You can read about `udev` at:

[Ubuntu Manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/udev.7.html)

I'm not a Python expert, but i have find a module about using  `udev`, so you can try with it:

[Pure Python udev bindings](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)